# Storing data in HashSets

Tags: java, hashset

I am trying to store the data of `roomNo` in the `occupiedRooms` `HashSet`. I'm unsure how to store the value. I have this so far: a validation condition which then, if correct, should store the `roomNo` in the `HashSet`; however, it does not.

```
public void checkIn (String roomNo, String guest) {

    if(!(validRoom(roomNo) && roomTaken(roomNo))) {
        System.out.println(guest + " booked in to room number: " + roomNo);
        occupiedRooms.add(roomNo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get console output?

Comment: You might need to use a ConcurrentHashMap instead, as there are no concurrrent Sets, and you want to have the atomic properties to avoid locking.

Comment: Your if seems strange, you should deal with validRoom and roomTaken differentely `if (!validRoom(r)) throw new IllegalArgumentException(); if (takeRoom(roomNo)) { System.out.prinltn("Room was free and is taken"); }`

Comment: Are you getting into the conditional statement? Are your validRoom method and roomTaken methods correct? What errors are you getting? Have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   public void checkIn (String roomNo, String guest) {
       if (validRoom(roomNo)) {
        if (!roomTaken(roomNo)) {
            System.out.println(guest + " booked in to room number: " + roomNo);
            occupiedRooms.add(new Room(roomNo,guest));
           }
        }
    }


public boolean roomTaken (String roomNo){
        if(!(occupiedRooms.contains(roomNo))){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;

        }

    }
```

Comment: I tryed it and its still give me an error on the .add method

Comment: thsis is inialziation occupiedRooms = new HashSet<Room>();

Comment: and the instnace vaiable is private  HashSet<Room> occupiedRooms;

Comment: ok so you can change occupiedRooms.add(new Room(roomNo)) for example

Comment: if the solution is correct sign it and up -vote this solution

Answer (score 0):

// The **validRoom** method is below //
    public boolean **validRoom**(String roomNo){

```
        String floorNo = roomNo.substring(0,1); 
        String rNo = roomNo.substring(1,3);
        int roomNoI = Integer.parseInt(rNo);
        int floorNoI = Integer.parseInt(floorNo);

        if(!(floorNoI > 7 || floorNoI <= 0 || roomNoI <= 12)){

            System.out.println("sorry room " + floorNoI + roomNoI + " number does not exsist at this hotel");
            return false;

        }

        System.out.println("Floor:- " + floorNoI +"\nRoom:-  "  + rNo );

        return true;
    }


//`And the *roomTaken* method just checks where the *roomNo* *Varable* is  stored in the *hashSet*//

public boolean roomTaken (String roomNo){
        if(!(occupiedRooms.contains(roomNo))){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;

        }

    }
```

// sorry im new to java just getting to grips with it 
    cheers for the help//

Comment: for logic in method roomTaken the value are reverse ... so you can try my solution .. for your problem